Is there a way to infer type when using `forwardRef`?
The Type inference works with normal component but doesn't work with forwardRef. I know the reason but still is there a way?

This what I mean by type inference
The Component File
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import type { Control, FieldValues } from 'react-hook-form';

import { FormError } from '@/components/form-error';
import {
    FormControl,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form';
import type { InputProps } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';

interface AppInputProps<
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
    TContext = unknown,
> extends InputProps {
    control: Control<TFieldValues, TContext>;
    label?: string;
}

const AppInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, AppInputProps>(
    ({ control, label, name, ...props }, ref) => {
        if (!name)
            return (
                <FormError message="Can't render input without 'name' attribute" />
            );
        return (
            <FormField
                control={control}
                name={name}
                render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>{label}</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                            <Input {...props} {...field} ref={ref} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                )}
            />
        );
    }
);

AppInput.displayName = 'AppInput';

export { AppInput };



You didn't show the code

Added it. please take a look now

Found out a weird but workable solution
import { forwardRef, type ForwardedRef } from 'react';
import type { Control, FieldPath, FieldValues } from 'react-hook-form';

import { FormError } from '@/components/form-error';
import {
    FormControl,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form';
import type { InputProps } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';

interface AppInputProps<
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
    TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
> extends Omit<InputProps, 'name'> {
    control: Control<TFieldValues>;
    label?: string;
    name: TName;
}

const LocalInput = <
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
    TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
>(
    { control, label, ...props }: AppInputProps<TFieldValues, TName>,
    ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>
) => {
    if (!props.name)
        return (
            <FormError message="Can't render input without 'name' attribute" />
        );
    return (
        <FormField
            control={control}
            name={props.name}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel>{label}</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                        <Input {...props} {...field} ref={ref} />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
            )}
        />
    );
};

LocalInput.displayName = 'AppInput';
const AppInput = forwardRef(LocalInput) as <
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
    TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
>(
    props: AppInputProps<TFieldValues, TName>,
    ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>
) => JSX.Element;

export { AppInput };



As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
